# Enabling versioning on multiple S3 buckets using AWSCLI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to enable versioning via awscli; ideally I would use the following:

```
aws s3 put-bucket-versioning --bucket <bucketname> --versioning-configuration status=Enabled
```

However, but we have hundreds of buckets. Is there a way to modify this command to enable it on all the existing buckets?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
aws s3 ls | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs -L 1 aws s3 put-bucket-versioning --versioning-configuration status=Enabled --bucket
```

The first part of this simply lists all S3 buckets and then pipes that listing into `cut` which strips that list of date and time, leaving just the bucket names. That list of bucket names is then piped to `xargs -L 1` to execute the subsequent `aws` command against each bucket name, one at a time.

To add additional filtering, for example to only list those buckets ending in `prod` or `dev`, add an additional pipe command before `xargs`:

```
aws s3 ls | cut -d' ' -f3 | grep -E "(prod|dev)$" | xargs ...
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I wanted to do it with just the ones ending with 'prod' or 'dev'

Comment: Have added additional filtering example. It's worth getting familiar with pipes in Unix and how to use (at least) the following: sort, grep, awk, sed, tr, head, tail, wc. You'll find all kinds of ways to use them to solve problems.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick one-liner, you might try:

```
for bucket in $(aws s3api list-buckets --query 'Buckets[?contains(Name, `prod`) == `true`]' --output text); do aws s3 put-bucket-versioning --bucket $bucket --versioning-configuration status=Enabled ; done
```

This uses a [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/) query filter to pick out just the buckets you need.